# Add a file into the ios app

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

I am a  newbie to iOS, I have a created a textfield and imageView in a ViewController. I want user of app to select an image or a file(.txt,.csv, etc)into the App. I know that Apple provides UIImagePicker to select images from the device. with these I added an image to my imageView.

Now I want to Know that is there any way to select files from the device and use it into application. Or else Open file system of device and select the file ?

When I Googled it, I got that you are not able to open the file system. So how can I implement this functionality in iOS app?

Comment: `when i Google it, i got that you are not able to open the file system.` probably because it's not possible? iOS doesn't allow you to access files in the system, except the ones you save inside the app sandbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way of selecting file from file system into application. You can only access files from

1. Default Photos App
2. Application Documents Directory
3. Any file from web server with use of API's

There are multiple ways from which you can select files of different types other than images are

1. Integrate [Dropbox](https://www.appcoda.com/dropbox-api-tutorial/) SDK into app
2. Integrate Google Drive
3. Integrate iCloud

So create one `UIButton` like "Select File" and open `UIActionSheet` on tap of it. `UIActionSheet` will have options like

1. Select From Photos
2. Select File From Dropbox
3. Select File From iCloud
4. Select File From Google Drive
   etc

And you can call respective actions on each `index`.

Answer (score 0):

You can pick your documents and images and other files by using separator picker for each like

for Documents - `UIDocumentPickerViewController`

for Images/Videos - `UIImagePickerController`

Apple does not provide a direct picker for all files.
Hope this is working for you. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`UIDocumentPickerViewController`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uidocumentpickerviewcontroller) if you enable iCloud document support for your app.

Answer (score 0):

you can not load files directly from file system, but you can load them from some third party applications like Documents and cloud sources like iCloud and Drop Box with [UIDocumentPickerViewController](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uidocumentpickerviewcontroller)